# How to pass data between tasks in Spring Cloud Composed Task?

Tags: spring-cloud-task

It appears to me that out of the box Spring Cloud Composed Task does not support passing parameters between tasks.

Can you please suggest some options for the below requirement?

a) I have a composed task in which downloader is the first task, once that completes then two more tasks say Item and Item Group runs. Once those completes, a transformation takes place.

b) I need to run the above composed task for different store (E.g store no 1, 2 etc...)

Even if we are using database to pass the parameters b/n task what's the unique id we can use to relate the composed task.

Comment: What platform are you running this on?

Comment: We are planning to run on Yarn Cluster.

Comment: Michael - You have any suggestion for the above use case?

Comment: Your use case looks like a nice example of Spring Data Stream. Did you consider use Streams instead of Composed Tasks?